# Stamp ink split of cover page and line of thread

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, passport-stamps

Stamp ink of front page has been split due to humidity and there comes one line near the thread, but thread is ok and holding the passport is properly. Let me know that is there any issue for getting visa and international travel in future.

Comment: TL;DR - No problem at all. Entirely normal.

Comment: No problem at all. If the passport cover comes off, or almost comes off, its a problem. You have to replace.